# For ECS deployment group, ec2TagFilters can not be specified

Tags: aws-cloudformation

When creating a AWS::CodeDeploy::DeploymentGroup in CloudFormation, I get this error, even though I have no EC2TagFilters in my script:

For ECS deployment group, ec2TagFilters can not be specified (Service: AmazonCodeDeploy; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidEC2TagException; Request ID: af5c3f68-6033-4df0-9f6f-ecd064ad6b7b; Proxy: null)

```
CodeDeploymentGroupDev:
  Type: AWS::CodeDeploy::DeploymentGroup
  DependsOn:
    - CodeDeployApplication
  Properties:
    ApplicationName: !Ref ApplicationName
    DeploymentConfigName: CodeDeployDefault.AllAtOnce
    DeploymentGroupName: !Sub "${ApplicationName}-Dev"
    DeploymentStyle:
      DeploymentType: IN_PLACE
    OnPremisesTagSet:
      OnPremisesTagSetList:
        - OnPremisesTagGroup:
            - Key: !Ref OnPremisesTagKey
              Type: KEY_AND_VALUE
              Value: !Ref OnPremisesTagValue
    ServiceRoleArn: !Sub 'arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/CodeDeployServiceRole'
```

Is AWS::CodeDeploy::DeploymentGroup not implemented correctly in CloudFormation?

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you are using OnPremisesTagSet which mean you should already register on-premises instances with CodeDeploy, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/instances-on-premises.html.

If you are using Ec2 then you need to use Ec2TagSet instead of OnPremisesTagSet.

Comment: The onprem instance is already registered. I am trying to match the tags to that instance so it only deploys to that opnprem instance. Also, even if I take that out completely, it throws the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

This occurred because my corresponding AWS::CodeDeploy::Application was not configured correctly (not in original post, but shown below). I was attempting an onprem deploy using a registered agent. I had ECS for the compute platform, but it should have been Server:

```
CodeDeployApplication:
  Type: AWS::CodeDeploy::Application
  Properties:
    ApplicationName: !Ref ApplicationName
    ComputePlatform: Server   // Allowed values: ECS | Lambda | Server
```

It worked, after I fixed that.